# How to set view as fragment listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener, onactivityresult

From inside a view I am calling a Fragment so that I can take a photo. I am setting the View as the listener

```
AuxPhotoFragment auxFragment = AuxPhotoFragment.newInstance(photoFile);
auxFragment.setOnPhotoTakenListener(this);
```

But `onActivityResult` the listener is found to be null. Any ideas how to pass a listener to a fragment when that listener is not the Context? For background see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617124/startactivityforresult-inside-view-crash-on-rotation

The fragment I am using looks like this

```
public class AuxPhotoFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PHOTO_FILE = "paramPhotoFile";

    private File photoFile;

    private OnPhotoTakenListener mListener;

    public AuxPhotoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static AuxPhotoFragment newInstance(File file) {
        AuxPhotoFragment fragment = new AuxPhotoFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_PHOTO_FILE, file);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            photoFile = (File) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_PHOTO_FILE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void setOnPhotoTakenListener(OnPhotoTakenListener onPhotoTakenListener) {
        mListener = onPhotoTakenListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode && Constants.REQUEST_CODE_SINGLE_PHOTO == requestCode) {
            mListener.addPhotoToViewAndContentProvider(getContext(), photoFile);
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public interface OnPhotoTakenListener {
        void addPhotoToViewAndContentProvider(Context context, File photoFile);
    }
}
```

And I am calling it with

```
AuxPhotoFragment auxFragment = AuxPhotoFragment.newInstance(photoFile);
                auxFragment.setOnPhotoTakenListener(this);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(auxFragment, TAG).commit();
                fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                auxFragment.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO);
```

Note: just as the original problem, I am having the null issue on rotation: i.e. I go into the camera, rotate, take a picture, then then accept the picture by clicking OK.

Comment: You may want to add some log output to the constructor of your fragment. The OS may be discarding the fragment you create and creating a new one. This can happen if the screen orientation is changed.

Comment: So how do I make it grab the same fragment it had before the orientation change?

Comment: yeah, the problem is that, after rotation you have new activity, so the listener is null. you need to setup the listener to the fragment after rotation. the easiest way to do that - check that instanceState is not null in onCreate and find this fragment by id or tag and set the listener.